# Connection Object fails to initialise

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, thread-safety, invoke

```
  Private Sub DGVTotalReport_CellMouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) 
 Handles DGVTotalReport.CellMouseDoubleClick
    Dim ExpForm As New ExpenseEntry
    My.Settings.TranCodeExpOpen = DGVTotalReport.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(8).Value


    If My.Settings.ExpenseForm = False Then
        If ExpForm.InvokeRequired = True Then
            ExpForm.BeginInvoke(Sub() ExpForm.Show())
            ExpForm.BeginInvoke(Sub() ExpForm.OpenVoucher())
        Else
            ExpForm.Show()
            ExpForm.OpenVoucher()
        End If


    End If
```

'''

```
  Dim CheckPaymentMode As String = "MY QUERY"

    Dim DACheckPaymentMode As New OleDbDataAdapter(CheckPaymentMode, LocalDatabaseCon)
    Dim DTCheckPaymentMode As New DataTable

    DACheckPaymentMode.Fill(DTCheckPaymentMode)   'The exception is thrown here as the connection fails to initialise
```

Here if the form has already been loaded earlier then if I call the above sub from another form, using the Invoke method, the data connection object still fails to initialise. What can I do to resolve this issue?

**Edit:It seems people are thinking this is happening on the same form but I am actually calling that sub from another form which seems to be throwing a threading error.**

Khalid.

**EDIT**

The `LocalDatabaseCon` is set using the following code in the form load event:

```
Private Sub ExpenseEntry_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim LocalDatabaseCon = New OleDbConnection
    LocalDatabaseCon.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & My.Settings.LocalDatabasePath
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you add the code that sets the variable `LocalDatabaseCon` please?

Comment: What possible reason could you have for checking whether you're on the UI thread in an event handler for a control? If you could possibly not be executing that method on the UI thread then you're doing something else wrong.

Comment: Is `LocalDatabaseCon` `Nothing` when that code executes? You should already know because you should already have set a breakpoint on that line and checked. If so, you should then have debugged the code that is supposed to set that variable. It seems like you are not yet at the stage of actually using the debugging tools provided by VS. You should stop what you're doing and learn how to use the debugger. It is essential for all developers and you should always have used it before posting a question here.

Comment: The `LocalDatabaseCon` is set using the following code in the form load event: `Private Sub ExpenseEntry_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        LocalDatabaseCon = New OleDbConnection
        LocalDatabaseCon.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & My.Settings.LocalDatabasePath  End Sub`  @jayv

Comment: Please don't put code in comments. It is too hard to read. I have edited your question and added the comment.

Comment: Why are you creating an Adapater and then overwritting it with another New Adapter?

Comment: Ok, that was my mistake. Thank you for pointing that out. But please guide me on how to solve the original problem I had asked here.